Dissapears icon in status bar for running timer
When I started the built-in timer in my tablet, the hourglass icon appeared in the notification bar. Some time ago, this icon doesn't appear.
How to return this icon to the status bar?
(Lenovo Tab P11 plus, Android 11)

If it's a normal notification, have you checked the app's notification settings and whether it's disabled?

@Andrew T., yes, I checked its notification settings, all notifications are enabled.

@Andrew T., you were right, the problem was in notification setting, it was only required to go deeper in setting and change something counterintuitive option — see my answer. Thank you for your useful tip.

Do this:
                Settings ⇾ Apps & notifications (1) ⇾ Clock (2) ⇾ Timers (3) ⇾ Default (4)
                (Numbers in parentheses correspond with numbers in following screenshots.)
No other option is required to change.
The problem was evidently caused by selecting “Silent” instead of “Default” (see the last screenshot).
The term “Silent” is in this context confusing, because it not means that the timer will not play any sound at the end of counting down to zero — it still will play it, only the hourglass icon will be replaced by the icon of muted loudspeaker.



